# This js code doesn't work in Safari 7.05?

Tags: javascript, safari

I made a simple voucher js code which works on pc (chrome, firefox) and mac (chrome), but it doesn't work on mac + safari 7.05

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var vouchersArr = ['stack98',
        'stack45'];

    $("#voucherCode").change(function() {

        if (~$.inArray($(this).val().toLowerCase(), vouchersArr)) {
            //$(this).val();
            if($(this).val().toLowerCase() == vouchersArr[0]) {
                $('#price').val(125);
                //alert('test '+document.getElementById("price").value);
            }
            if($(this).val().toLowerCase() == vouchersArr[1]) {
                $('#price').val(95);
                //alert('test '+document.getElementById("price").value);
            }

        } else {
            $(this).val('Not a valid code');
        }
    });//end change 
});
```

How should i fix this one?

Comment: What does not work exactly? Did you debug to see what is failing. `console.log()` is your friend.

Comment: @epascarello well it's a very strange error the second vouchercode stack45 doesn't work, formfield #price is not set to 95. But the exact same code works on domainB with mac+safari, but it does not work on domainA. On domainA both vouchercodes work in mac+chrome and only the first code work on Mac+safari???